# Debugging Link Token Creation Through Python Plaid API Connection

Tags: python, json, plaid

I am hoping to get some support regarding an error I've been getting from the Plaid API that I get when trying to connect via Python. I've attached a screenshot of the code I'm using to this ticket (with personal information replaced with 'xxx'). Essentially, I've been following the documentation and cannot get past the step of creating the link token.

Every time I run the attached code, I get an "Invalid Body" error saying "body could not be parsed as JSON". I can't understand where I'm going wrong as I'm using the sample/provided code exactly. I've been banging my head into the wall trying to figure this out, any help would be much appreciated.[Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLS1f.png)

Comment: Don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try following the sample code in the docs or sample apps. For example, when using the client libraries, you should never send the `client_id` or `secret` as body parameters, because they are sent as headers by the client libraries. The code in the docs and sample apps doesn't do that.